# Firefox & Chrome: difference in mailto: with html tags

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, mailto

Entering the following URL leads to different results, depending on the used browser:

```
mailto:?body=<b>Text</b>
```

When entering the URL in Chrome, the HTML code inside the e-mail body gets rendered correctly (Thunderbird and Gmail).

**Text**                                   (chrome)

But when entering the URL in Firefox, the HTML inside the e-mail body is not rendered (Thunderbird and Gmail).

<b>Text</b>            (firefox)

Why?

Ubuntu 19.04
Chrome: Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox: 69.0 Firefox Release September 3, 2019

Answer (score 1):

The different browser behaviour is justified, given that passing HTML in the mailto link can be reasonably considered a security liability. Based on your testing, I'd say Chrome just strips the HTML from the body content before passing it to the mail application, while Firefox leaves it intact.

However, how browsers handle this isn't really the point. The problem is that you shouldn't be using HTML in the body field of a mailto link in the first place. See [RFC 6068 - The 'mailto' URI Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068):

> The special  "body" indicates that the associated 
> is the body of the message.  The "body" field value is intended to
> contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the
> message.  The "body" pseudo header field is primarily intended for
> the generation of short text messages for automatic processing (such
> as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not for general MIME
> bodies.

Therefore, how different browsers and mail clients handle it isn't really the point. I'd say the behaviour you observed in Firefox is more standard-compliant; since the mailto link is expected to create a plain text email, the HTML tags are passed along as-is (or maybe they're encoded into HTML entities under the hood) to the mail client, to be displayed as plain text. In the same sense, it's also reasonable for mail clients to create a plain text email from mailto links.

### Solution

The answer to your problem is simple, don't use HTML in the mailto body field. It's non-standard, so you can't expect consistent support in different mail clients and browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've seen the RFC and I've read that it is not standard-complaint. But still I was wondering why they behave so differently and if I have any chance to change their behavior. Are there any resources where such things might be documented?